# DynamoDB stack type logging

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I'm trying to log some program's output to DynamoDB table, 
but I need to keep let's say only the last 5000 rows. 
What's the best way to achieve that? 
I mean it's sounds like a bit extreme to check every single time when I need to put something in there and check if that would overfill the limit, retrieve the first row and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you do it in RAM?  You would use a circular buffer.  Do the same thing on DynamoDB.  Each time you write to the table, increment the primary key and modulo it 5000.